# How can I rewrite this list comprehension as a for loop?

Tags: python

How can I rewrite this using nested for loops instead of a list comprehension?

```
final= [[]]  
    for i in array_list:
        final.extend([sublist + [i] for sublist in final])


    return final
```

Comment: What do you mean "typical for loop"?

Comment: You want to rewrite a for loop as a for loop?

Comment: the second loop is done using a "single-line" for loop. I would like to implement it like the first for loop. I tried it but I get Memory error

Comment: The problem is that if you iterate over final as you extend it, you're essentially iterating over an infinite list, because every time you go to the next element, you add another one. You need to either keep your code the way it is, or iterate over a copy of final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to iterate over final as you extend it, it creates an infinite loop. Because every time you go to the next element, you add another element, so you never reach the end of the list.

If you want to do the inner loop as a for loop instead of a list comprehension, you need to iterate over a copy of final.

```
final = [[]] 
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    for sublist in final[:]:
        final.extend([sublist + [i]])
```

Comment: @patrickhaugh Yes, currently it does, but op wants to use nested for loops.

Comment: Not true, they don't need to iterate over a copy. Try `for j in range(len(final)): final.append(final[j] + [i])` for example.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sure, but that's far less idiomatic with zero benefits.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Less memory usage isn't zero benefits. Anyway, the "need" claim is just wrong. Btw, I'd really use `append` instead of `extend`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks to be a very good `for` loop one.  A one-liner using `itertools` is possible, but ugly

```
list(itertools.chain(list(itertools.combinations(arr, i)) for i in range(len(arr) + 1)))
```

EDIT:

Prettier:

```
list(itertools.chain(*[itertools.combinations(arr, i) for i in range(len(arr)+1)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code also seems to give the same results as your code.

```
final = [[]]
for i in array_list:
    for sublist in list(final):
        final.extend([sublist + [i]])
return final
```

It seems like your code takes the elements of the last iteration and combines them with the element of the current iteration (See 'Example' below). In order to do this with a traditional for loop, you need to prevent the list that is being looped over from being updated while looping. I do this by breaking the link with the 'final' list variable. This can be done with the list() function or by slicing it (then you would need to replace  with  as proposed by Morgan).

**Example**

For the array_list of [1,2,3] you get the following. Each line (except for the lines) is a new element of the 'final' list variable.

```
[]
--------------------------------
1           > array_list[0]
--------------------------------
2           > array_list[1]
1, 2        > array_list[0] + array_list[1]
--------------------------------
3           > array_list[2]
1, 3        > array_list[0] + array_list[2]
2, 3        > array_list[1] + array_list[2]
1, 2, 3     > array_list[0] + array_list[1] + array_list[2]
```